# Rechecking bags on international-to-international connection in Mexico City

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, mexico, mex

My friend has a flight from Lima (LIM) to London (LHR) via Mexico City (MEX), all on one ticket with Aeromexico.

I understand that Mexico, like the US, doesn't do sterile transit, so he'll have to pass Mexican immigration.

**Will he also need to collect and re-check his checked bag**, like in the US, or will it be loaded directly onto the second flight (like when transiting pretty much anywhere else)?

Comment: Are you sure about the lack of sterile transit?  [this](https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs) suggests that bags will be checked straight through.

Comment: @PeterM I'm not sure, but it looks like the page you linked has the answer, at least for the baggage question. Thanks!

Comment: I've no experience with airports in Mexico, so I don't know if they differentiate between passengers and luggage during international transfers.  Hence being a comment only.  Other posters do have a lot of MEX experience.

Comment: Are you sure there’s no sterile transit? Timatic says “_TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Passengers transiting through Mexico City (MEX) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination_”. Looks like they only have sterile transit in MEX and not in other airports in the country but that they do have it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Passenger FAQs page of the MEX website](https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs) indicates in section 4b that bags are checked through:

> If your connection is just part of an international trip, your baggage will be checked in for its final destination.